# Reqest from mysql grouping by dates with gap

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table:

**table1**

```
id value date
1  2     2014-10-11 17:24:16
2  3     2014-10-12 13:24:16
3  2     2014-10-12 15:24:16
4  2     2014-10-12 17:24:16
5  4     2014-10-14 11:24:16
6  2     2014-10-14 13:24:16
```

I would like to get results below:

```
value date
2     2014-10-11
7     2014-10-12
0     2014-10-13
6     2014-10-14
```

How can I do this in mysql? Thanks.

P>S: Where is that row:  **0     2014-10-13** ?

Comment: MySQL cannot generate the date gap, unless you have another table with all dates and join with it.

Comment: You can use php to show date gap.

Comment: It will be problem with pagination...

Comment: edited my answer, this would display date gaps with value 0 in the middle of the query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you need to generate all the dates in your range and then use `left join`.  The following is one method:

```
select d.d, sum(t1.value) as value
from (select date('2014-10-11') as d union all
      select date('2014-10-12') as d union all
      select date('2014-10-13') as d union all
      select date('2014-10-14') as d
     ) d left join
     table1 t1
     on date(t1.date) = d.d
group by d.d
order by d.d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value, DATE(date) As Date 
FROM Table
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value,  DATE(date) AS date
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$a = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT SUM(value) AS value,  DATE(date) AS date, DAYOFMONTH(date) AS day FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE(date)");
WHILE($a2 = mysqli_fetch_array($a))
{
    if($daycheck == "")
    {
        $daycheck = $a2[day];
    }
    else
    {
        if(($daycheck + 1) != $a2[day])
        {
            for($x = ($daycheck+1); $x<$a2[day]; $x++)
            {
                $date_new2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($daycheck2 . ' + 1 day'));
                echo "0-----".$date_new2."<br>";
                $daycheck2 = $date_new2;
            }
        }
    }
    echo $a2[value]."-----".$a2[date]."<br>";
    $daycheck = $a2[day];
    $daycheck2 = $a2[date];
}
?>
```

this will display 0 value for no dates result in the middle of the results

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(value) as value, DATE(date) FROM <table> GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
Select sum(value), DATE(`date`) from table1 group by DATE(`date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value,
       DATE(date) AS date
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by

```
select sum(value) ,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%d-%m') as date from MyTable group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%d-%m')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81917/3)